# Yii2: rest api model get data

Tags: rest, websocket, yii2

I am using REST API in my project and everything works great. I describe a model using a model

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\models;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Yii;

class Comment extends \common\models\Comment
{
    public function fields()
    {
        return [
            'id',
            'user' => function(Comment $model) {
                return User::findOne($model->user_id);
            },
            'text',
            'image' => function(Comment $model) {
                return Yii::$app->params['link'].$model->image;
            },
            'created_at' => function(Comment $model) {
                Carbon::setLocale(Yii::$app->language);
                return Carbon::createFromTimeStamp(strtotime($model->created_at))->diffForHumans();
            },
            'children' => function(Comment $model) {
                $comments = Comment::find()
                    ->where(['comment_id' => $model->id]);
                if (!$comments->exists()) {
                    return false;
                }
                return $comments->all();
            },
            'like',
            'news_id',
            'comment_id'
        ];
    }
}
```

The data is returned in the specified format and that's great. But I need to send data to the controller using websockets. For example, when a new comment arrives, send it to all users.

```
$post = Yii::$app->request->post();
            $image = UploadedFile::getInstanceByName('image');
            $model = new \api\modules\v1\models\Comment([
                'news_id' => $post['feed_id'],
                'comment_id' => $post['comment_id'] ?? null,
                'user_id' => Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
            ]);
            $model->text = $model->findLinks($post['text']);
            if ($image && !$image->error) {
                if (!file_exists(Yii::$app->params['comment.pathAbsolute'])) {
                    if (!FileHelper::createDirectory(Yii::$app->params['comment.pathAbsolute'], 0777)) {
                        throw new \Exception('Помилка створення папки');
                    }
                }
                $serverName = Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString(16).'.'.$image->extension;
                if ($image->saveAs(Yii::$app->params['comment.pathAbsolute'].$serverName)) {
                    $model->image = $serverName;
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception($image->error);
                }
            }
            if (!$model->save()) {
                throw new \Exception($model->error());
            }
            Helper::ws(false, 'updateComment', ['feed_id' => $post['feed_id'], 'comment' => $model]);
```

And when I pass the $model, the data is passed as it is stored in the database. Is it possible to call a method or something so that the data is passed as I described in the model api?

Comment: Did you try to use `$model->toArray()` method when passing to ws gateway?

Comment: thank you, just what you need. but when i do like this `$comments = \api\modules\v1\models\Comment::find()
                ->where(['news_id' => $post['feed_id']])
                ->andWhere(['OR', ['IS', 'comment_id', new Expression('NULL')], ['comment_id' => 0]])
                ->orderBy('id desc')
                ->asArray()
                ->all();` it outputs as it is in the database

Comment: `Query::asArray()` and `ActiveRecord::asArray()` are not the same. For `Query` it sets the flag to not create an `ActiveRecord`. For `ActiveRecord` it runs method from the `ArrayableTrait`. Just only in this case method `fields()` is used.

Comment: so when i select the data i can't get it back in the format i want?

Comment: As I understand, you need call `Comment::find()->...->all()` without `->asArray()` and then iterate result collection and call `->toArray()` for each ActiveRecord object. See `vendor/yiisoft/yii2/rest/Serializer.php` source code for the reference. It is serializer class for the API call results.